# Variables of parent class to all childs

Tags: php, oop

I have a class structure like that:

```
class general {

    private $var;

    function set_val( $val ) {
        $this->var = $val;
    }

    function get_val() {
        return $this->var;
    }

}


class A extends general {

    function __construct( $val ) {
        parent::set_val( $val );

    }

    ....

}


class B extends general {

    ....

}
```

and the corresponding main script is like that:

```
<?php
$a = new A( "Apple" );
$b = new B();

echo "A: " . $a->get_val();
echo "B: " . $b->get_val();
```

which outputs:

```
A: Apple
B:
```

The problem here now is that all instances of A and B accesses their own variable $var of parent class general whereby all $var are independent from each other.

Is there a way that one set the variable $var in the parent class general **once** which then is avauiilable autmatically to **all classes** which are childs of/extends general? (Thus $b->get_val() outputs "Apple", too?!)

Background: I want to load variables with language-dependent values in the general class. These variables should then be available to all child classes.

Answer (score 1):

Data is not automagically shared between different objects. You could use a `static` class property that you access statically, which is essentially a global variable. This is usually a bad idea though, since the encapsulation offered by objects is usually thought to be a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if in your code you want objects to share common data, its better to separate them out in another object  and use that object in the code.

Example: The language independent data could go into a separate class which caters to the language independent functionality. However if you need to use only one class due to some constraints then the only option is to have them as static members of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Declare    $var    as    protected    instead of     private.
Private variables are only available to classes that declare them and not to the child classes.
Protected variables are available to both the defining class and all classes that extend the parent class.

Comment: Even with protected declaration there will not be the "Apple"-Value set by the A object available to the B object?! Thus the output does not change...?!